# How to display output of 2 commands in ansible?

Tags: linux, ansible, ansible-playbook

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  user: 
  become: yes

  tasks:

  - name: Checking current kernel on Target Server
    shell: hostname;uname -r
    register: output
  - debug: msg= "{{ output.stdout }}"
```

Comment: What You get And what You want to get?

Answer (score 4):

Remove the space after "=". Correct syntax is

```
- debug: msg="{{ output.stdout }}"
```

, or

```
- debug:
    var: output.stdout
```

, or even better

```
- debug:
    var: output.stdout_lines
```

Answer (score 3):

While Vladimir is correct about dumping out stdout of commands with debug, kernel release and hostname can be accessed with a minimal amount of fact collection:

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: True
  gather_subset: min
  become: False

  tasks:
  - name: hostname
    debug:
      var: ansible_hostname

  - name: kernel version
    debug: 
      var: ansible_kernel
```

- Your variables are available without registering anything. You also get some bonus facts like `ansible_distribution`
- The `min` facts set is sufficient, which skips a lot of hardware detection and is fairly fast.
- Becoming a privileged user was not necessary.
- Avoided a use of `shell`. Which has less obvious failure modes than fact collection.